# GitHub SSL: invalid CA certificate #1

Tags: git, ssl

I have initialized a github repository in an existing folder, every time i try to push it it gives me this error

git push -u origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myUsername/NLPFFSPI.git/': SSL: invalid CA certificate #1 (offset 0) in bundle

I have searched online and nothing helped. I also reset my certificates, still the same. Does anyone know what this means??

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS and git version, as well as your PATH and environment varialbles.

On Windows, for instance, try the same [with a simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47826648/6309), to avoid any side effect of other programs.

On Mac or Linux, check your `.curlrc`. Check if you are using openssl (not securetrnasport, [as in this issue](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/11451#issue-211490001))